# Servlet session attribute size and lifetime

Tags: java, session, servlets

1) What is an acceptable size range of objects that should be attached to a session? If I attach an object that can be 5k, and I have 10k valid sessions at any given time, that's 50MB of memory which seems acceptable to me. Is that a valid way to approach the issue, or are there other significant concerns?

2) This is probably a dumb question, but if I attach an object to a session with a 2 week lifetime, can I access the attribute as though it were in memory for the whole duration of the session?

3) Is there any reason NOT to always persist session information to a DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Acceptable size depends on your use case and number of concurrent sessions.  If your sessions last 2 weeks, then it is conceivable that you could have a lot of concurrent sessions, but if 10k is your anticiapted maximum then there should be no problem with a 5k session object (as your calculation illustrates).
2. As long as you have a reference to the session object (or are able to get such a reference) then the data will persist in the session.  Remember that your session objects must be serializable.
3. You may not want to persist all session data to a db for performance reasons, especially if the session data can be easily recreated.

Answer (score 3):

1. Java EE does not limit the size of HTTP session. The RAM requirements for your webapp are going to be x + su * s, where "x" is everything else, "su" is the maximum number of concurrent session users, and "s" is the session object size itself. So, if this is an app with no more than 5 users, go for it. If it has 1500 users, you may want to reconsider. The time required for serialization/deserialization of each session object is going to increase more or less linearly with the size of the object. So if lots of serial transformations are expected, be prepared.
2. You can as long as your session is alive.
3. Persist sesion data is expensive performance-wise you should do it only when you need session replication in cluster for recovery reasons.